# Django - Get distinct data from field

Tags: django

I'm looking for getting distinct objects from my database with `distinct()` command.

I have this model :

```
class CoefficientIntervention(models.Model):

    Technicien = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Coefficient Technicien")
    Ingenieur = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Coefficient Ingénieur")
    Consultant = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Coefficient Consultant")
    Architecte = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Coefficient Architecte")
    Societe = models.ForeignKey(Societe, related_name="ste", verbose_name="Société", default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode (self.id, self.Technicien, self.Ingenieur, self.Consultant, self.Architecte, self.Societe)
```

My form looks like :

```
class CoefficientFormulaire(forms.ModelForm) :

    Societe = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Societe.objects.filter(), required=True, label = "Societe", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s' % (obj.id, obj.Nom))

    class Meta :
        model = CoefficientIntervention
        fields = ['Technicien', 'Ingenieur', 'Architecte', 'Consultant','Societe']
```

And my view is really simple :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Societe_Coefficient(request) :

    if not request.user.is_superuser :
        raise Http404


    coefficient = CoefficientIntervention.objects.order_by('Societe').values('Societe').distinct()
    print coefficient

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CoefficientFormulaire(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            post = form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Le formulaire a été enregistré !')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Coefficient'))

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Le formulaire est invalide !")

    else:
        form = CoefficientFormulaire()

    context = {
        "coefficient" : coefficient,
        "form" : form,
    }

    return render(request, 'Identity_Societe_Coefficient.html', context)
```

My table has 3 lines for example :

[image]

If I print `coefficient`, I get : `<QuerySet [{'Societe': 2L}, {'Societe': 3L}]>`

But I would like to display distinct objects in my array and take the last one each time.

My template looks like :

```
<table class="lg-tableau-coeff">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Coefficient Technicien</th>
                    <th>Coefficient Ingénieur</th>
                    <th>Coefficient Consultant</th>
                    <th>Coefficient Architecte</th>
                    <th>Société</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in coefficient %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Technicien}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Ingenieur}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Consultant }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Architecte }}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Societe.Nom}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How I can do that ?

**UPDATE :**

With MySQL, the command is :

`SELECT * 
 FROM Identity_coefficientintervention
 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Identity_coefficientintervention GROUP BY Societe_id)`

So I have to find How I can translate it to Django Query

Comment: Use annotated queries, for some guidelines look at: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html

Comment: or the Django documentation on [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)